# Click the second button of an img in VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba, button, click

I'm trying to click an imagebutton on IE by using getAttribute("src"), but there are to identical buttons with the same src-code, so when I use this code, it clicks the first and I want to click the second. Can somebody help me?

**I'm thinking of creating a loop to search through and choose the second one, but I have no idea how to write the code! Can somebody help me out?**

This is the code I use to click the first button:

```
Set allInputs = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("img")
For Each Element In allInputs
If Element.getAttribute("src") = "/forms/Content/Images/0006.gif" Then    
Element.Click     
Exit For    
End If     
Next Element
```

The HTML code for the buttons are:

```
<tr class="jqgfirstrow" role="row"      
<tr tabindex="-1" class="ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr" id="1"     role="row"
< img src="/forms/Content/Images/0006.gif"  

<tr tabindex="-1" class="ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr" id="2" role="row
< img src="/forms/Content/Images/0006.gif"
```

Comment: Change the line "Element.Click" with "Element.NextSibling.Click" and try to execute.

Comment: You can also try to get element by "ID" they both have different id.

Comment: `allInputs` will be an collection, so `allInputs(2).click` or `set e=allinputs(2):e.click` something along those lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all of your help!

I did it with code here:

```
Set allInputs = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("img")
allInputs(2).click
```